# How to skip script triggering while executing Application Import in Maximo?

Tags: jython, maximo

While importing a csv file, a script that checks for additions/changes is triggered.

How can I skip this triggering? Or, how can I detect the Application import in my script to stop execution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check whether `interactive` is true. For an Application Import, it will be false, like it is for all integration.

Alternatively, you could include an indicator in your data. For example, many objects have a `SENDERSYSID` attribute that you could set to `IMPORT`. Your script could then be adjusted to only do its job where `sendersysid is null or sendersysid != 'IMPORT'`.

To "include the indicator in your data", you will need to ensure the Object Structure you are importing against Includes, or doesn't Exclude, the attribute into which you will load your indicator. You then need to include that attribute in your data load with the value you use to indicate this record came from a data load.

For example, imagine you were loading work orders with an Object Structure called `MXWODETAIL`, and you were going to set `SENDERSYSID` to `IMPORT`. First, you would change your script to not do its processing when `SENDERSYSID` is set to `IMPORT`. Next, you would go to the `MXWODETAIL` Object Structure, load the Exclude/Include Attributes dialog and make sure `SENDERSYSID` does not have Exclude checked. Then, you would add the indicator to your data, like this:

```
SITEID,WONUM,DESCRIPTION,SENDERSYSID
BEDFORD,1010,"Your work order description",IMPORT
```

Now, when you load this data, your script will see your indicator and not do its processing.

Comment: actually interactive comes up as true and sendersysid as null, unless I'm pointing to a wrong mbo, which I'm clueless if it's different from current mbo

Comment: Thanks!, it actually worked by setting mxe.int.interactiveimport to false then, checking for interactive == true as you suggested

Comment: Marking my answer as accepted, or at least giving it an upvote for being helpful, would be appreciated.

Comment: @cluna Do you have any cron jobs or such that would need your script to run?  If so you might still want to set the sendersysid and check for it.